# How to create vowel counter in python

Tags: python

Title says all!
I am trying to make a " Display Stats" option in my menu i created. It would display the following after inputing a sentence. For example:
String Analysis:
6 words
26 Characters
9 Vowels
17 Consonants.
I made the whole word and character counter already now i need to do vowel and consonants, can someone help me please? Id highly appreciate the support!

What i got so far:

```
def displayst():
    print()
    print("You said the following:")
    time.sleep(1)
    length = str(input("Please enter your sentence: "))
    word = dis(length)
    lengths = diss(length)
    vowel = disv(length)
    print(length)
    time.sleep(1)
    print()
    print("String Analysis:",'\n', word, "Words",'\n', lengths, "Characters",'\n',vowel,"Vowels",'\n')
    again()
```

The vowel = disv(length) is what i need to finish and if you could help with consonants that would be great! If not i mainly need the vowels done as consonants i guess i could give it a try haha.

Then in my disv(length):

```
vowels = 'aeiou'
count = {}.fromkeys(vowels,0)
for char in length:
   if char in count:
        count[char] += 1
print(count)
```

Its all crazy and i honestly havnt a clue where im going with this haha. 
Please help cheers.

Comment: So what is the issue? your code seem to work...

Comment: When i run the program i get this:
You said the following:
{'a': 0, 'o': 1, 'u': 0, 'e': 1, 'i': 0}
hello

String Analysis: 
 1 Words 
 5 Characters 
 None Vowels 


Would you like to make another selection?
1. Yes
2. No.

Comment: "It's all crazy" is not a sufficient problem description (unless your dealing with timezones).

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-5wpm-gesOY&ab_channel=Computerphile

Comment: Yeah well what i mean by crazy is, its giving me: {'a': 0, 'o': 1, 'u': 0, 'e': 1, 'i': 0} when i type "hello" for the input, i want it to give me a number of how many vowels are exactly in the sentence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not returning anything from disv that's why it is saying vowels None.You can use `counter` to get the vowel count

```
from collections import Counter

x = Counter(length)
vowel_count = 0
for v in "aeiou":
    vowel_count += x[v]
return vowel_count
```

This will return the exact number of vowels in your sentence.

Comment: Wow, thank you very much! It worked perfectly.
I was spending so much time trying to change things around for a workable solution and bayum! Answer in seconds, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a count, use a Counter dict:

```
from collections import Counter

inp = input("Please enter your sentence: ").lower()
cn = Counter(inp)
vowels = {v: cn[v] for v in "aeiou" if v in cn}
cons = {c: cn[c] for c in "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz" if c in cn}
```

if you want the total count just sum the values:

```
 print(sum(vowels.values()))

 print(sum(cons.values()))
```

If you just want the sums:

```
vowels = sum(cn[v] for v in "aeiou")
cons = sum(cn[c] for c in  "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxy")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def getInput():
    sentenceInput=input('Enter your sentence: ')
    return sentenceInput

def count(sentenceInput):
    vowelList=['a','e','i','o','u']
    vowelCount = 0
    constCount = 0
    spaceCount = 0
    for char in sentenceInput:
        if char in vowelList:
            vowelCount += 1
        elif char == ' ':
            spaceCount += 1
        else:
            constCount +=1
    print ('Length: ' + str(len(sentenceInput)) + ', Words: ' + str(spaceCount) + ', Vowels: ' + str(vowelCount) + ', Consonants: ' + str(constCount))

count(getInput())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
vcount = sum([s.count(v) for v in 'aeiou'])
```

The list comprehension in side the [] returns a list of the occurrences of each vowel. The outer sum sums up the counts to give a total vowel count.

Comment: Yeah, I don't understand why everyone is using a counter. This is fine.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham What do you mean?

Comment: Yes, I don't understand the relevance, unless you're referring to time complexity. Otherwise, this accomplishes the desired task.

Comment: You don't need a list here; remove the square brackets and you get a generator expression, which is generally more time- and space-efficient. It doesn't make much of a difference here, but it's a good thing to know about.